# How to assign value to a Docker ARG in docker.build Jenkinsfile?

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, dockerfile, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to assign a value to a Docker ARG, using Jenkinsfile, so I can use it as a dynamic ENV variable depending on the pipeline.

The problem is that the env does not appear in the container and this warning is displayed in the job console output:

```
One or more build-args [MY_ARG] were not consumed
```

Am I making a typo error in the code? Or is the flow wrong?

Here's my **Dockerfile** part:

```sh
ARG MY_ARG
ENV MY_ENV=${MY_ARG}
```

**Jenkinsfile** stage:

```groovy
def runDockerStages(version) {
    def dockerImagePath = "${PROJECT_DIRECTORY}/${PROJECT_NAME}:${version}"
        def VALUE = "This is a test"

    docker.withRegistry(DOCKER_REGISTRY_HTTP, CI_USER) {
        sh 'cp conf/Dockerfile ./'

        stage ('Docker build') {
            dockerImage = docker.build(dockerImagePath, "--MY_ARG='${VALUE}' .")
        }

        stage ('Docker publish') {
            dockerImage.push()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd expect the `docker build` option to be `--build-arg MY_ARG=$VALUE`; but I'd also expect you to get a command-parsing error with the option as you've shown it.

Comment: This is actually not intended documented usage for the `build` method from the library for the Docker plugin for Jenkins Pipeline, but it may still actually work with some modifications. Note the first argument is also supposed to be the image name, and the second argument is the path to the `Dockerfile`.